# Redirect to index page after submiting form in django

Tags: python, django

Everything works correctly apart from redirecting back to the index page after adding the products data, currently after my data gets save it gets redirected to **127.0.0.1:8000/product/add_product/add_product**

Currently when my index page(add_product.html) loads, I have a table that renders data from the database,

1. first my url looks like >> **127.0.0.1:8000/product/**
2. Then once I hit the add button url changes to **127.0.0.1:8000/product/add_product/** , no problem there, but
3. when i try to add data again my url goes to **127.0.0.1:8000/product/add_product/add_product** and i get a Page not found error

My views.py

```
from models import Product,Category
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response,get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def index(request):
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('product/add_product.html', {'category_list': category_list, 'product_list':product_list})

def add_product(request):
    post = request.POST.copy()

    category = Category.objects.get(name=post['category'])
    product = post['product']
    quantity = post['quantity']
    price = post['price']

    new_product = Product(category = category, product = product, quantity = quantity, price = price )
    new_product.save()
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('product/add_product.html', {'category_list': category_list, 'product_list':product_list})
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns = patterns('product.views',
    url(r'^$', 'index'),                       
    url(r'^add_product/$', 'add_product'),
)
```

How do i get the URL pointing back to my index page(add_product.html) ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the view of **127.0.0.1:8000/product/add_product/**  return this

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def add_product(request)
    ...........................
    ...........................
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

It will redirect to index page.
Also try to give **url name** so that you can use **reverse** instead of '/'

Thanks

Comment: It worked, I had to add "return HttpResponseRedirect('/product')" since its inside the product template folder, thanks alot @Paritosh Singh

Comment: ok try to use url reverse by giving name to urls, plz don't hardcode urls, it will affect maintainaiblity of code.

Comment: Ok will look into it now, i am still learning django, thanks for the tips

Answer (score 6):

You may have set your form's `action` incorrectly in your template.

Instead of a relative url,

```
<form method="post" action="add_product">
```

the action should have the absolute url:

```
<form method="post" action="/product/add_product">
```

As an improvement, you can use the [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag, so that you don't need to hardcode the url in the template.

```
{% load url from future %}
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add_product' %}">
```

The snippet above uses the new url syntax, by loading the new url tag.

Comment: thanks for that, while keep the current  url render_to_response as in the question and only making the changes according to what you said also works perfectly

Comment: You can only choose one answer on stack overflow, but in your code, you can use both answers together! Redirecting after a successful update is a good idea -- it prevents the user from accidentally refreshing and submitting the same data multiple times. Using the `url` tag is good practice as well.