# Django - calling function does not redirect

Tags: python, django, redirect

I want to redirect and return view after submiting form on my homepage. Unfortunately after POST nothing is happend.

My homepage:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.POST['url']
        bokeh(request,url)
    return render(request,'home.html')

def bokeh(request,url):
    //my calculation logic
    return render(request,'bokeh.html')
```

Of course I send other attributes like dictionaries etc, but it works fine when I hardcode my url in browser. After clicking submit on my form in my homepage nothing is happend.

**EDIT**

my bokeh function look like that:

```
def bokeh(request,url):

    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    descrp = [description.text for description in soup.find_all('p', class_="commit-title")]
    author = [author.text for author in soup.find_all('a', class_="commit-author")]
    dict1 = dict(zip(descrp,author))
    dict2 = dict(Counter(dict1.values()))
    label = list(dict2.keys())
    value = list(dict2.values())

    plot = figure(title='Github Effort',x_range=label,y_range=(0,30), plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
    plot.line(label,value,line_width = 2)
    script,div = components(plot)

    return render(request,'bokeh.html',{'script': script,'div': div})
```

and my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^bokeh/(?P<url>\w+)/$',views.bokeh,name='bokeh',url='url'),
]
```

And at this moment I got TypeError: url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'url'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect to index page after submiting form in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12671649/redirect-to-index-page-after-submiting-form-in-django)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not return the result of the `bokeh` function:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.POST['url']
        return bokeh(request,url)
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

Note however that this is *not* redirecting, and therefore you do *not* implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). In case of a successful POST request, it is usually a good idea to perform a redirect, to prevent a user from refreshing the page, making the *same* POST request. A POST request frequently has side effects, and therefore we want to omit that.

You better make use of the [**`redirect(..)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) here:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        url = request.POST['url']
        return redirect('bokeh', url=url)
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

You should not use a `url=…` in the `url(..)` function:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^bokeh/(?P<url>\w+)/$', views.bokeh, name='bokeh'),
]
```

Comment: Ok, so 1st method works fine - I get what I want, but it's still at the same endpoint (just content of homepage changes, there is no redirect to localhost:8000/bokeh what I expected.
The 2nd method doesnt work - probably I got something wrong with my urls.py (url(r'^bokeh/',views.bokeh,name='bokeh'))

Comment: @Frendom: no there is no redirect. You simply call the functin, and return the response of that function. As said before, it is furthermore not a good idea to call the function in the first place. You should return a `redirect` with the name of the `bokeh` view, and then let the client make a second request.

Comment: @Frendom: since the name of that view is `bokeh`, it thus should be `redirect('bokeh', url=url)`. But you forgot to add a `(?P<url>...)` parameter to you `url(..)`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.re_path

Comment: @Frendom: you should omit the `url='url'` parameter.

Comment: Im getting NoReverseMatch for 'bokeh' with keyword arguments '{'url': 'url I just sent'}'

Comment: @Frendom: did you use an `app_name`?

Comment: @Frendom: note that `\w+` only contains word characters. So no `/`, `:`, `.`, `?`, `#`, `-`, etc.

Comment: I've never used app_name because it worked fine to this moment

Comment: so how correct pattern would like to look? Or is there a must to us him?

Comment: You can use `(?P<url>.+)`